# Error while delivering code in RTC

Tags: eclipse, xulrunner, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I m setting up RTC on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit. My RTC and JDK7 are also 64 bit versions. Whenever I try to deliver code using RTC I get an error:

```
Error logged from Process Client UI: 
No more handles [MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME='/opt/xulrunner/'] (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /opt/IBM/TeamConcert/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/613/1/.cp/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3659.so (libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
    swt-mozilla-gtk (Not found in java.library.path)
    /tmp/swtlib-64/libswt-mozilla-gtk-3659.so (libxpcom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
    /tmp/swtlib-64/libswt-mozilla-gtk.so (/tmp/swtlib-64/liblibswt-mozilla-gtk.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
)
```

I ran this on my system:

```
$ ldd libswt-mozilla-gtk-3659.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff5bff000)
    libxpcom.so => not found
    libnspr4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007ffc49b3e000)
    libplds4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007ffc49939000)
    libplc4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007ffc49734000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ffc49431000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffc49134000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffc48f1e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffc48b5f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffc48941000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffc4873d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ffc48535000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffc49eb6000)
```

Answer (score 2):

This [jazz.net thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/73602/error-saving-repository-workspace-in-rc0-ubuntu-1110) mentions:

> This is an eclipse problem ([bug 343889](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=343889)).
>   Many of the linux distributions recently underwent an upgrade to xulrunner-2.0 which is incompatible with some versions of eclipse. (even with `xmlrunner-compat` packages)
>
> Check the version of your xulrunner.
>   If it is 2.0, you may want to either shut off your embedded browser in RTC (not recommended)
>   --or-- what I do is install RTC into a standard eclipse Indigo distribution which DOES work with xulrunner-2
>   --or-- downgrade to previous xulrunner (1.9)

(That or there is an [installation issue with the current xulrunner](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/47436/xulrunner-issue-on-linux-mozilla_five_home-fixed))